# graph url scopes not supported for smtp and imap

Tags: email, azure-active-directory, smtp, microsoft-graph-api

For authentication, we are using below scopes as mentioned in the doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

offline_access
https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
We are able to get access_token and refresh_token successfully

We want to get userPrincipalName but https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/ api doesn't return userPrincipalName.
We tried using graph api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me to get userPrincipalName
however we are getting error , looks like for hitting graph api only graph scopes would work.

We tried with graph scopes urls,

https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All , https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send
and able to hit graph api , however smtp and imap authentication is not working with these scopes.

since Microsoft is deprecating outlook rest apis and asking to move to graph api
then why graph scopes urls are not supported for SMTP and IMAP ?

Is there any way we can get the userPricipalName ?

Comment: When you use `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/` to get the information of the logged-in user, what error happened?

Comment: @CarlZhao no error comes, we are able to get the user details successfully, however in the response , userPrincipalName is not there which we require. userPrincipalName is there in the graph api  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, but this gives error since the scopes are outlook scopes and not graph scopes

Comment: Hi, Do you have the opportunity to research my answer? was it useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` and `SMTP.Send` are added to MS graph api, and then grant admin consent.

[image]

Then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token.
[image]

Call the `/me` endpoint.

[image]

Comment: The token which we get by this method have graph url scopes : https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send
If we try to authenticate smtp using these token we get authentication error.
For smtp authentication only outlook url scopes work:  https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
Ref- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth